# JSON format in Sublime Text 3 compiler build file

Tags: json, c++11, sublimetext3

I'm trying to compile a c++11 file in Sublime Text3 on Mac OS Sierra with this JSON configuration, but unfortunately the print statements dont appear in the 'compiled' text box.

```
{
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$", //from c++ build file     
    "shell":true,
    "shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++11 \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -v -e '^/var/folders/*' -e '^[[:space:]]*.section' -e '^[[:space:]]*^[[:space:]]*~*' && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
    "syntax" : "Packages/User/CPPoutput.tmLanguage",
}
```

-However they do print when the "shell_cmd" is replaced with

```
"shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++11 \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"  && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
```

-but my compiler will print out MANY various warnings that read like this

```
/var/folders/cj/1h3_84h56c9bgzt_ryhpf4940000gn/T//ccrbyBrV.s:103:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/cj/1h3_84h56c9bgzt_ryhpf4940000gn/T//ccrbyBrV.s:103:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
...and so on and so on
```

How do I fix the JSON file, and are there any other solutions? (I'd prefer to fix the syntax in the JSON file, but either way.  Thanks.  From what I understand, these warnings are only printed with the latest mac os (sierra).

Comment: Are you trying to let regular output through but filter some messages? You may be running afoul of the fact that `2>&` redirects `stderr` to `stdout` (which is probably what you want) but `> /dev/null` sends all output to the bit bucket, so there's nothing for the following grep to work on. I would try without the `> /dev/null` part and see what you get.

Comment: @OdatNurd  I tried your suggestion and the result was the same.  Btw, I meant to uncomment the very last portion of "shell_cmd" which shoud read ...*~*' && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"

Comment: Unsure what you're asking here; If you mean the first one doesn't show your program output it's because the part of the line that runs it is commented out (as you mention). That's easy to fix though, just remove `",//"` and the string is valid JSON. It still won't show compiler output though because you're sending the entire output of the build process to `/dev/null`.

Comment: @odatNurd I actually did that in my edit, but it didn't show cause I had to approve it.  Yeah, weird error...